80s/90s children TV show with "superpowers" household objects
Looking for a children live-action TV-series that I used to watch in the 90s. I remember that there were only a few episodes (mini-series) and that it was most likely of British or Australian production.
The plot revolved around a group of children who tried to find all of the pieces of a fallen star (?). When the star fell it was split in several pieces and each piece was absorbed by a common object, giving it some supernatural powers. I recall that there was a T-shirt which granted invisibility and a vacuum-cleaner which allowed to travel back in time.

It's The Miraculous Mellops (1991) , a sci-fi/comedy television series, created by Posie Graeme-Evans and produced by Film Australia & Millennium Pictures in association with the Network Ten. 

The series centered on a group of teenagers, two brothers and a
  sister; Michael, Jason and Samantha Mellop. A year earlier, their
  mother has died and their family business, 'The Lazy Daisy Nursery' is
  run by their rationalist father Bill and absent-minded Aunt Josey. The
  general plot of both seasons were the strange events that the Mellop
  teens would often get caught up in, without their father or aunt
  noticing and/or believing them.
The first season centred on the "Search for the Grand Baby" plot. An
  alien race of children exist on the moon, known as Moonlings. Their
  leader, The Grand Baby, is fast approaching the end of his life, and
  without an heir, it is decided that a great power will be sent to
  Earth to choose a new leader for the people there. The power itself,
  consisting of all the psychic and magical abilities that the Grand
  Baby possessed, arrived on Earth but hit the Mellops' crystal
  punchbowl, "splitting" around the house, hitting several household
  items.
Suddenly, the Mellop teens start to notice the powers associated with
  the items. For example; the T-Shirt of invisibility, the baseball
  cap of flight, the vacuum cleaner of time travel and even the
  toothpaste of linguistic ability. Of course, it isn't long before the
  Dumps hear of the powers, and concoct their own schemes to get a hold
  of the powers for selfish purposes such as business ventures by
  Bernie. Seeing no harm in the use of the powers, Michael Mellop,
  smitten with Harmony's charms, would often help the Dumps acquire the
  powers.Wikipedia

Episode 1.2  (T-Shirt of invisibility)

The dog collar and the frilly apron enable the kids to communicate by
  telepathy. Michael's favourite T-Shirt makes him disappear and he
  sneaks into Dump's office. He hides the dog collar in Dump's hat to
  tune in to his thoughts and foil his next move. Michael tries to
  impress the beautiful Harmony with the T-shirt of invisibility but she
  tells her father  Bernie Dump!

Episode 1.8 (The vacuum cleaner of time travel)

The Grand Baby has only days to live, but attempts to reach Jane by
  telephone are hampered by Dump. Bill orders the kids to vacuum and
  Ralph is watching a dinosaur show on TV when his foot hits the power
  button and both he and the vacuum disappear. Ralph is nowhere
  around—instead he's clutching the vacuum cleaner and wandering in a
  primeval swamp of 300 million years ago, inhabited by giant dinosaurs.
  The Miraculous Mellops: episode guide

Clip: The Miraculous Mellops - T-shirt Of Invisibility
